# How to let a bidirectional relation not create foreign keys on both sides when adding another relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Code-First Entity Framework making a simple bidirectional relation between two classes named `Sector` and `Ship`. The idea here is that a `Sector` can have zero-to-many `Ships` where a `Ship` always has a `Sector`, it's current location.

For navigational purposes I'd like to have a property on either side of the relation. So class `Sector` contains a property of type `ICollection<Ship>` where `Ship` contains a property of type `Sector`.

The primary key of `Sector` is a combination of `X` and `Y`.

```
public class Ship
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }

    public virtual Sector Sector { get; set; }
    //public virtual Sector Destination { get; set; }
}

public class Sector
{
    public Int64 X { get; set; }
    public Int64 Y { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        // combined key for sector
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sector>()
            .HasKey(s => new { s.X, s.Y });
    }
```

Results in tables:

```
Sector
 - X
 - Y
Ship
 - ID
 - Name
 - Speed
 - Sector_X
 - Sector_Y
```

The issue is that as soon as I make a another relation between `Ship` and `Sector`, namely it's `Destination`, the previously mentioned relation is created with a foreign key on both sides. Firstly, I wonder why, and secondly how to prevent it from happing? I don't see the need, and it results in the first relation not being navigable from both sides because either `Sector_X` and `Sector_Y` are `NULL` or `Sector_X1` and `Sector_Y1` are `NULL`. The represent the same thing.

```
Sector
 - X
 - Y
Ship
 - ID
 - Name
 - Speed
 - Sector_X
 - Sector_Y
 - Destination_X
 - Destination_Y
 - Sector_X1
 - Sector_X2
```

Comment: I think EF might be getting confused because it doesn't know whether `Sector.Ships` is the inverse of `Ship.Sector` or `Ship.Destination`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look under "Relationship Convention" on [Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx), it says

> If you have multiple relationships between the same types (for example, suppose you define the Person and Book classes, where the Person class contains the ReviewedBooks and AuthoredBooks navigation properties and the Book class contains the Author and Reviewer navigation properties) you need to manually configure the relationships by using Data Annotations or the fluent API.

Since you have multiple relationships between `Ship` and `Sector`, EF cannot determine which navigation property on `Ship` is the inverse of the collection property on `Sector`, and creates a separate relationship for `Sector.Ships`.

You will need to use the [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Relationships) (here's one example, but there are other ways to do this):

```
public class Sector
{
    public Int64 X { get; set; }
    public Int64 Y { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Sector")] 
    public virtual ICollection<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
}
```

or [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // other stuff...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Ship>()
        .HasRequired(p => p.Sector)
        .WithMany(p => p.Ships);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Ship>()
        .HasRequired(p => p.Destination)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

Because `Sector` has multiple 1:many relationships with `Ship`, you will probably have to use Fluent API because you will need to set at least one of the relationships to not cascade delete by default (or set `Ship.Destination` to optional?) or you will get the "multiple cascade paths" error.

Answer (score 1):

When adding the `Destination` property you will also want to include a navigation collection on `Sector` class, `IncomingShips` for example. Or do not add any navigation collections on `Sector` class.

I am assuming EF gets confused when there are 2 navigation properties from `Ship` to `Sector` but only one `Ship` collection in `Sector` so it goes ahead and creates 3 FK pairs.

Use:

```
public class Ship {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }

    public virtual Sector Sector { get; set; }
    public virtual Sector Destination { get; set; }
}

public class Sector {
    public Int64 X { get; set; }
    public Int64 Y { get; set; }
}
```

-- OR --

```
public class Ship {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }

    public virtual Sector Sector { get; set; }
    public virtual Sector Destination { get; set; }
}

public class Sector {
    public Int64 X { get; set; }
    public Int64 Y { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ship> IncomingShips { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    .....
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sector>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Ships)
                .WithRequired(p => p.Sector)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Sector>()
                .HasMany(p => p.IncomingShips)
                .WithRequired(p => p.Destination)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Both should result in tables:

```
Sector
 - X
 - Y
Ship
 - ID
 - Name
 - Speed
 - Sector_X
 - Sector_Y
 - Destination_X
 - Destination_Y
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion of having the `IncomingShips` property as this seemed useful to me. It is, however, jjj's answer that got me to understanding the "why" around my problem. Between the two of you, you managed to help me out, I do believe that his answer should be the accepted one simply because of the referenced theoretical background. I do kindly thank you for your addition though. +1